# How to create \in-symbol with underbar that has rounded edges and correct vertical spacing?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, underline, definition, relation-symbols

The **aim** is to create a **new symbol** `\ineq`. The appearence of `\ineq` would be to `\in` as `\subseteq` is to `\subset`.

- Output from attempt at making `\ineq`:

  [image: Output from attempt at making \ineq]

- Problems with attempt in decreasing order of importance. **(1)** The underbar in `\ineq` is rectangle-shaped, not with rounded edges as `\subseteq`, `\leq`, `\leqslant`, `=` etc. **(2)** The distance between underline and `\in` should be increased slightly to match the spacing of underbars in `\subseteq` and `\leq`.
- MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%% my attempt
\newcommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{ \raisebox{0.3ex}{\mbox{$\underline{\mkern-1.8mu\in\mkern-1.53mu}$}} }}
%%%%

\begin{document}

\( A \ineq B \subseteq C \leq D \leqslant E = F \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: ⋸ is U+22F8 which is `\isinvb` in `unicode-math`, `stix`, `stix2`, and compatible packages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the information! Detexify did not seem to find it based on my drawings; with your help, I found it in the *Comprehensive List*. I'm using ``pdflatex``. Importing ``stix`` would change the outlook of the document too much. The symbol ``\isinvb`` in ``stix`` packages is atomic, meaning that it's not defined from existing symbols (a construction I could otherwise have copied). Maybe one can import it from ``xits``? I am not sure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the meaning of this symbol in your work?

Comment: @dbmag9 Happy to satisfy your curiosity :-). It is to denote, in mostly interim fashion, the semantic notion which its syntax implies. Namely, ``a ⋸ b`` would be ``a ∈ b or a = b``. (Similar to how ``a ⊆ b`` would be ``a ⊊ b or a = b``.) In my opinion at least, ``⋸`` makes some notation shorter and terminology simpler for ordinal numbers in set theory, where ordinals are well-ordered wrt ``⋸`` (strictly well-ordered wrt ``∈``).

Comment: @LinearChristmas Ah, ordinals, that makes sense! I wasn't sure what context you'd be in where membership versus equality was a likely pairing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

Vincent's [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652662/82917) reminded me of `\dabar@`, of whose existence I completely forgot. This allows to set up a slightly better version of my original answer (see below)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\in@eq\relax}}
\newcommand*{\in@eq}[2]{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{\m@th$#1\in$}%
   \setbox\tw@=\hb@xt@\wd\z@{\m@th$#1\dabar@$\hss$#1\dabar@$}%
   \vcenter{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \box\z@
      \vskip-.1\ht\tw@
      \copy\tw@
      \vskip-.5\ht\tw@
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \ineq \supseteq B$

$\scriptstyle A \ineq \supseteq B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \ineq \supseteq B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Not pretty but an approximate realization. The main idea is to use a minus sign, which, however, is somewhat larger than `\in`, that's why I cheat a bit ans use `\subset` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\in@eq\relax}}
\newcommand*{\in@eq}[2]{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{\m@th$#1-$}%
   \vcenter{%
      \m@th
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr
              $#1\subset$\llap{\copy\z@}\cr
              \noalign{\kern-.5\ht\z@\kern\dp\z@}%
              \copy\z@\cr
              \noalign{\kern-.5\ht\z@}%
      }%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \ineq B \subseteq C \leq D \leqslant E = F$

$\scriptstyle A \ineq B \subseteq C \leq D \leqslant E = F$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \ineq B \subseteq C \leq D \leqslant E = F$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The universe... in which I could have realised this solution in TeX by myself... does not intersect our known Universe :-). Thank you, I like the output! Minor quibble: the symbol's ``\ineq`` output is *slightly too low*. It should be about...``0.06ex`` higher, maybe? Where should I put the ``\raisebox`` in this case?

Comment: @LinearChristmas Uhm, too low with respect to what? I've taken care that it's aligned with `\subseteq`.

Comment: See red line in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1idbI.png). It is quite minute. Of course, doing something like ``\newcommand{\Ineq}{\mathrel{\raisebox{0.07ex}{\ensuremath{\ineq}}}}`` works, but I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: It is also visibly present on the two bottom lines of your answer. But it might be due to something else as it is tiny... maybe the PDF-editor, maybe the picture capturing software, maybe the monitor...

Answer (score 5):

This will produce virtually identical height and depth as `\subseteq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ineq@\relax}}
\newcommand{\ineq@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\in$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\wd\z@}%
    \setlength{\dimen@}{%
        \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3 \else
        \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3 \else
        \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3 \else
        1.1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3 \fi\fi\fi}%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\cr % right alignment
      $#1\in$\cr % \in
      \noalign{
        \vspace{0.28625\unitlength}
        \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\vspace{-0.05\unitlength}\fi
      }
      \begin{picture}(0.75,0)
      \roundcap
      \linethickness{\dimen@}
      \Line(0,0)(0.75,0)
      \end{picture}\hspace{0.175\unitlength}\cr
      \noalign{\vspace{0.5\dimen@}}
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\ineq \subseteq B$
$\scriptstyle A\ineq \subseteq B$
$\scriptscriptstyle A\ineq \subseteq B$

\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\ineq$}\fbox{$\subseteq$}

\end{document}

\sbox0{$\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{$\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{$\scriptstyle\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{$\scriptstyle\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\large$\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\large$\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\large$\scriptstyle\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\large$\scriptstyle\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\Large$\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\Large$\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\Large$\scriptstyle\ineq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\sbox0{\Large$\scriptstyle\subseteq$}\the\ht0--\the\dp0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove the first `\end{document}` to see also a comparison of height and depth at various sizes. At 10pt size we get

[image]

so you see that the difference is at most 0.01pt.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution (which only works in `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, but could be adapted if needed).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\shortminus}{%
    \dabar@\hspace*{-3.3pt}\dabar@%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\ineq}{\mathrel{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{1pt}{$\in$}\cr%
        \raisebox{-3.6pt}{$\shortminus$}%
    }%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(A \in B \subset C \quad A \ineq B \subseteq C\)
\end{document}
```